# reusable ui components using nibs

Tags: ios, xib

I like using interface builder to design ui elements but am designing a screen in which different subviews display depending on conditions. For me its easier to design those subviews in seperate nib files and then load them into the view controller when needed.

e.g. I have the following activity view that is lazy loaded that is basically an overlay that displays an activity indicator, I would like the option to reuse this in different view controllers.

Here is the getter method in one of the view controllers

```
- (ActivityView *)activityView
{
    if (!activityView) {
        activityView = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ActivityView" bundle:nil]
                instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }
    return activityView;
}
```

In the nib file I do not set the owner to match the view controller as I would like multiple view controllers to be able to use it, but I link the top level view to an ActivityView class so I can customize some of its ui programatically.

This approach seems to work for me but I wonder if this is a good approach?

In the resource programing guide it says:

Important: You are responsible for releasing the top-level objects of any nib files you load when you are finished with those objects. Failure to do so is a cause of memory leaks in many applications. After releasing the top-level objects, it is a good idea to clear any outlets pointing to objects in the nib file by setting them to nil. You should clear outlets associated with all of the nib file’s objects, not just the top-level objects.

I was not sure if this was still applicable if I have ARC and what I would need to do about it?

Does this just mean I need to set self.activityView = nil in the didReceiveMemoryWarning method?